# Android push notification using MQTT

Tags: android

I am new to Android MQTT , I refere this link http://jason-sherman.blogspot.in/2012/08/android-mqtt-with-activemq.html , https://bitbucket.org/antlabs_dev/android-mqtt-client/src/fb9ab18dfe6d?at=master ,http://dalelane.co.uk/blog/?p=1599 and try to implement that code , But not getting proper result... Can anyone help me.. I want to push Notification Using MQTT.. Thanks in advance...

Comment: What is 'not getting proper result'? Do you get errors? What goes wrong?

Comment: Thanks for reply , Just loader is appear for connection nothing happens.... where to configure conf/activemq.xml in Android?